# Writing tests in Mojolicious for checking type of file attachment fails

Tags: attachment, mojolicious, perl

I am trying to write tests in Mojolicious for checking if an image attachment was sent correctly from a form.
I have a form containing `<input type="file" name="image_upload" accept="image/*">`. In the controller I am checking if `$self->req->upload('image_upload')->headers->content_type =~ /image/`. The tests, on the other side, send the image file as `form => {image_upl => { content => 'abc', filename => 'x.png' }}` inside the post request. Running the application works well, but the check fails inside the testing code. I don't really understand how those headers are set, so that I can send a mock image inside the post request.

Here is the code:

```
#Router.
$if_admin->post('/attachment/:page_id/add')->name('on_attachment_add')
  ->to('attachment#on_add');

# Client side (Mojolicious template).
<%= form_for 'on_attachment_add' => { page_id => $self->stash('id') }
        => (method => 'POST') => (enctype => "multipart/form-data")
        => begin %>
    <input type="file" name="image_upload" accept="image/*">
% end

# Controller (on_add)
my $self = shift;
my $image_file = $self->req->upload('image_upload');
if (!$image_file || $image_file->slurp eq "" || !$image_file->headers ||
    !$image_file->headers->content_type ||
    !($image_file->headers->content_type =~ /image/)) {
  $self->render(
    template => 'validation/invalid_data',
    status => 400
  );
}

# test.
$t->post_ok('/attachment/test_page/add' => form => {
  image_upload => { content => 'aaa', filename => 'x.png' },
  image_name => 'new_image.jpg'
})->status_is(200);
```

Comment: That huge conditional is very hard to read. Is not very maintainable.

Comment: Hm simbabque you're right actually, I was trying to obtain an MVP so I put all those checks in there. I'm changing it to something more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking here http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent/Transactor#tx I added `'Content-Type' => 'image/png'` to the hash reference in the form as such:

```
$t->post_ok('/attachment/test_page/add' => form => { image_upload =>
  { content => 'abc', filename => 'x.png', 'Content-Type' => 'image/png' },
  image_name => 'new_image.jpg'
})->status_is(200);
```

This solved the problem.